# Ruby on Rails Devise after_sign_in_path_for called on unrelated controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

struggling for a few hours on this one now. I have integrated the Devise gem into my Rails project after originally making my own auth system but I am facing an issue I can't understand.

When the user signs in the method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  user = resource_or_scope
  user_path(user.username)
end
```

Is triggered to redirect the user to their profile.

I have an edit user route which takes the user to a page in which they can edit their details and add a 'wanted item'. Two separate forms with two separate controllers and actions.

The 'add wanted item' method posts to a different controller that rendered the view called `WantsController` and adds a wanted item for the user through an association.

For some reason the `after_sign_in_path_for` method is called when submitting this form? It has nothing to do with signing in...

Here are my routes:

```
    #users/auth
    devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations]
    devise_scope :user do

      # registration
      get "/signup", to: "users#new", as: :sign_up
      post "/signup", to: "users#create", as: :sign_up_create

      # account
      get "/:username/account", to: "users#edit", as: :user_account
      put "/users/:id", to: "users#update", as: :user_update

      # shows
      get "/:username", to: "users#show", as: :user
      get "/:username/interests", to: "users#interests", as: :user_interests
      get "/:username/offers", to: "users#offers", as: :user_offers
      get "/:username/trades", to: "users#trades", as: :user_trades

      # auth
      post "/signin" => 'devise/sessions#create', as: :sign_in
      delete "/signout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :sign_out

      #wants
      resources :wants, only: [:create, :destroy]

    end
```

If I place the `wants` resource outside of the devise scope (which is where I expect it should go) I receive the following:

*Could not find devise mapping for path "/wants"*

What's happening here? Stumped!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Argh, silly mistake. Why is it after hours of struggling that when you post a question on Stack Overflow you figure it out after like 5 minutes?!

I had copied and pasted my RegistrationsController into the WantsController file to save typing the controller code but forgot to make it inherit from ApplicationController rather than Devise::RegistrationsController.

Lesson: Don't copy and paste!